# Apple Watch charger not charging

Tags: charging, apple-watch, charger

I have an Apple Watch Sport. Today I tried using a car port to charge my Watch. However, it does not work. I used the same charger and port yesterday and it worked fine. Why is my Apple Watch not charging?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some basic trouble shooting.  You have two components to check:

1. The 12v power port in your car
2. The charger

Plug your charger into the power port of a different car with a power port you know to be good.  If your charger works, then the problem is related to your car.  If it dosen't work, then your charger is at fault.

Alternatively, you can plug a known working charger into your car.  If it works there as well, it's your charger.  If it doesn't, it's your car.

Comment: Works in two cars.

Comment: There's your answer.   Your charger is working.  The problem is with your car.

Answer (score -1):

I found it easiest to make this flowchart myself:
[image]